# show/hide table in PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, css

I need to hide a table using if condition inside my following PHP code. I'm trying to use CSS for this but it seems CSS cannot read the if condition and it always runs and overrides.I want to implement it without taking table creation tags inside the if condition. Thanks

```
<?php
$arr=array(array(1,2,3,4,5),array(6,7,8,9));
foreach ($arr as $val)
{
    echo '<table border="1" id="table1" align="center"   style="float:center;">';
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($val);$i++)
    {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$val[$i].'</td></tr>';
        if($val[$i]>5)
        {?>
            <style>
            #table1 { visibility:hidden; }
            </style>
            <?php
        }
        else
        {?>
            <style>
            #table1 { visibility: visible !important;}
            </style>
            <?php
        }
    }
    echo'<br/>';
    echo '</table>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You'd want to consider a pure JavaScript solution as it is more suited to complete these sort of actions. Also why do create the table within the `foreach`?

Comment: This is very bad better use classes in css or even do it in JavaScript. If you want to hide rows then don't change style for whole table i won't work because second style last style will override what was before

Comment: I had to make my code simpler for here, it is way more complicated than this and inside the foreach there are lots of other actions so tables need to get generated foreach element of $arr.

Comment: I need to hide the whole table not just the rows. I tried classes in CSS but I get the same result.

Comment: javaScript is your best friend in this kind of situation.  if condition will work fine with js

Comment: Can you suggest a javascript solution?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
  $arr = array(array(1,2,3,4,5), array(6,7,8,9));
  $id = 1;
?>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .hidden {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
foreach($arr as $val) :
  for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($val); $i++) :
    if($val[$i] > 5) :
      $hidden = true;
    else :
      $hidden = false;
    endif;
  endfor;
  ?>
  
  <table border="1" id="table' . $id++ . '" align="center" class="<?php if($hidden) : ?>hidden<?php endif; ?>">
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($val); $i++) : ?>
      <tr><td><?php echo $val[$i]; ?></td></tr>
    <?php endfor; ?>
   <br/>
  </table>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure why I am attempting to answer this. I'm not even sure which table you're trying to hide. You're also not creating a well defined relationship between the data in one table and the table that should be hidden based on the value of that data.

Your inline CSS isn't going to work as you're using the same ID multiple times. You can't do:

```css
#table1 { visibility: hidden; }
#table1 { visibility: visible !important; }
```

The browser will apply the last rule to both tables. Instead use a CSS class that you generate in your loop.

```
.table-0 { visibility: hidden; }
.table-1 { visibility: visible !important; }
```

Something like this:

```php
<?php

$arr = array( array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ), array( 6, 7, 8, 9 ) );
$c   = 0;
foreach ( $arr as $val ) {

    $tClass = 'table-' . $c;

    echo '<table border="1" class="' . $tClass . '" align="center"   style="float:center;">';

    for ( $i=0; $i < sizeof( $val ); $i++ ) {

        echo '<tr><td>' . $val[ $i ] . '</td></tr>';

        if ( $val[ $i ] > 5 ) {            
            ?>
            <style>.table-0 { visibility:hidden; }</style>
            <?php
        }

    }

    echo '<br>';
    echo '</table>';

}

?>
```

Though this will get you what you want, there's still a lot to be desired. Mainly not injecting the CSS where you are - you're going to output a `<style>` for each value in the second array. Also, I'm pretty sure `<style>` is not an allowed child of `<table>`, the `align` and `border` attributes are depreciated and there is no `float: center;`.

I'm also wondering if you meant to use `visibility: hidden;` vs `display: none;`.

Consider doing something along these lines, could still use some improvement but better. We're not outputting more `<style>` than we need to.

```php
<?php

$arr    = array( array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ), array( 6, 7, 8, 9 ) );
$c      = 0;
$toHide = '';

foreach ( $arr as $val ) {

    $tClass = 'table-' . $c;

    echo '<table border="1" class="' . $tClass . '">';

    for ( $i=0; $i < sizeof( $val ); $i++ ) {

        echo '<tr><td>' . $val[ $i ] . '</td></tr>';

        if ( $val[ $i ] > 6 ) {
            $toHide = $tClass;
        }

    }

    echo '<br>';
    echo '</table>';

}

echo '<style>.' . $toHide . ' { visibility: hidden; }</style>';

?>
```

Some improvements could be to convert `$toHide` to an array and `push` each class into the array and then `implode` later if you had to handle multiple classes.

Comment: valiant answer!  went above and beyond